# Avoiding name collisions when creating external tables on SQL Server datawarehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to migrate a database `AdventureWorks` using Polybase to SQL Server datawarehouse.

Suppose I have a schema `HumanResources` and a table `Department` in that schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [HumanResources].[Department]
(
    [DepartmentID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

I need to create an external table for the data of `[HumanResources].[Department]` before loading the data from Azure blob into SQL Server datawarehouse.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ex.TableName 
(
    [DepartmentID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
WITH (
    LOCATION='/path/',
    DATA_SOURCE=AzureStorage,
    FILE_FORMAT=TextFile
);
```

I am creating all external tables under an `[ex]` schema, how should I represent the original schema to avoid collisions.

I cannot do `[ex].[HumanResources].[Department]` and I would like to avoid creating unnecessary schemas for external tables.

Is there an easy way of representing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern we see is to simply add _ext to the end of the table name. So following your example you'd have the following:

[HumanResources].[Department]
[HumanResources].[Department_ext]